# How to sort/filter grdiview columns by the displayed value rather than datafield value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, telerik, radgrid

My searches thus far haven't turned up anything fruitful - I suspect it's that I'm just not fluent in the terminology. How do I sort by what's displayed in the grid view, rather than the data that's behind it?

For example, my SQL datasource has a list of departments (stored as numbers). When I display the departments on the gridview, I call a function that does a lookup and returns the department name:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" Visible="True" DataField="CurrentDepartment" SortExpression="CurrentDepartment">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# gclass.GetDepartmentNameByDeptNumber(Eval("CurrentDepartment"))%>'
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Sorting this column orders the results by the numeric representation of the departments.

I run into a similar problem when I'm using Telerik's RadGrid with filters. I can search by the numeric values, but not the displayed values:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-Width="175px" FilterControlWidth="165px" Visible="True" DataField="CurrentDepartment" SortExpression="CurrentDepartment" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartment" runat="server" Text='<%# gclass.GetDepartmentNameByDeptNumber(Eval("CurrentDepartment"))%>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Suggestions and links are welcome!

Comment: Please post the code for your grid view's `Sorting` method.

Comment: @Karl Anderson - I'm just using the TemplateField/GridTemplateColumn's "Sort Expression".

Comment: You have to manage this thing manually by using custom sorting in RadGrid. OR If you want this functionality automatically by using RadGrid then you have to create one separate property for this in your class.

Comment: @Jayesh Goyani - I figured as much. Can you recommend exactly how I manage this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this looking for the same answer, I never did come across how to change the sort/filter logic.

What I ended up doing was modifying my Stored Procedure that returns the data. 
Instead of pulling from just the one table, I joined 4 tables and returned all the columns I needed.

So instead of calling a function to display the data in an ItemTemplate/GridTemplateColumn, I can now just use a BoundField/GridBoundColumn and display straight from each of the tables. 
This allows the sort & filter to work without modification.